# How to map Class<?> in JPA (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I'm writing an application using Hibernate and I was wondering how should I map an entity defined as:

```
@Entity
public Class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private Class<?> clazz;

    // getters/setters...
}
```

Is it possible to map this to a DB? Should I add an extra annotation to `clazz`?

Note that this is a curiosity, I'm not in a hurry this time, so please do not try to supply *alternate solutions*. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: That kind of depends on what you need to store, right? Do you just need the name of a class? Do you need to know its fields? This is a bit broad of a question.

Comment: I need to map in such way that I get the `Class<?>` object when calling `myEntityDao.getById(1L)` or something like that, do I make myself clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no JPA mapping for a `Class` object out of the box, but to satisfy most (if not all) use cases, you could do something like this

```
@Entity
public Class MyEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String clazz;

    public Class getClazz () {
        return this.clazz != null ? Class.forName(this.clazz) : null; 
    }

    public Class setClazz (Class clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz.getName();
    }
}
```

In this case, you are simply storing the name of the class as a String, and then when you retrieve it from the database, the getter will convert it into a proper class object.

Comment: very good! Also I could have a method `public Class setClazz(Class clazz){this.clazz = clazz.getName()}`. So you're taking full advantage of the **encapsulation** concept. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Sure, the above example was for brevity's sake, so the setter was sort of implied, but I'll add it for good measure.

Comment: Sure, I supposed that and wanted to add more info as suggested by the comment textbox's placeholder. Very appreciated anyway. Best regards